# Comandos CMD con video

Tags: cmd

Como hacer para que se ejecute completamente un video, al finalizar debe ejecutarse un .exe, he intentado con

```
@echo off
start vlc.exe C:\Users\Admon\Desktop\carpeta\VideoIntro.mp4
timeout /t 80> NUL
start C:\Intro\intro.exe
exit
```

pero no me responde adecuadamente, ya que intro.exe solamente debe cerrarlo el usuario

Comment: Cuando dices "ya que intro.exe solamente debe cerrarlo el usuario", ¿te refieres a que el problema es que el ejecutable se cierra solo?
Disculpa, no logré entender la pregunta.

Comment: Ariel Montes, muchísimas gracias por tu intéres en ayudarme, cuando menciono que solo lo puede cerrar el usuario me refiero a que el presiona la tecla "ESC", el proceso es asi:  Existen las siguientes variable; (1) el archivo VideoIntro.mp4 (2) el programa intro.exe. Entonces se crea un archivo en el que primero se ejecuta (1) y luego (2), si durante la ejecución de (1) el usuario presiona la tecla  "ESC", se inicia el proceso (2). Anticipadamente Gracias por los consejos/ayuda que me proporciones. Saludos y un abazo virtual

Comment: La tecla `esc` no hace nada al interno de vlc de modo que tendrías que estar en cmd para apretar esc y obtener algún resultado, pero tampoco veo en tu script ningún intento de detectar si se presiona esa tecla. Tu código funciona, si el video dura 80 segundos el programa debería ejecutarse al finalizar el video, supongo que solo le falta finalizar el proceso del vlc tras el timeout.

Comment: Con esto debería ser suficiente: `START vlc.exe VideoInto.mp4` 
`TIMEOUT /t 80> NUL` 
`TASKKILL /IM vlc.exe /F` 
`START intro.exe`

Comment: Si  cambio a la opción de mediaplayer, quedaria así:

@echo off
start wmplayer C:\Videointro.mp4 / pantalla completa
timeout /t 80> NUL TASKKILL /IM wmplayer.exe /F 
start C:\Intro\intro.exe
exit

como haria para activar la tecla ESC

este cambio lo hago porque conoci a alguien con quien comente
lo que estaba trabajando, y me manifesto que no sabia que era
el VLC (increible pero asi es)
P.D. Disculpa, pero la edición no me acepta CTRL+B

Comment: Sigo sin entender lo que deseas hacer con la tecla `ESC`. La función de esa tecla depende de la ventana que esté enfocada, en el caso de wmplayer `ESC` sirve para salir de la pantalla completa; si por otro lado quieres que `ESC` haga algo estando enfocado el terminal CMD entonces tendrás que crear idear la forma de capturar el evento key-up de la tecla `ESC`.

Comment: Con la tecla ESC deseo que el video deje de funcionar, (con esto el usuario puede suspender el video), más no la ejecución del archivo bat. Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Amigo, la verdad creo que no he logrado explicarme bien, así que lo intentaré nuevamente: La función de la tecla `ESC` en los reproductores de video es la de salir de la pantalla completa y no la de cerrar el programa, debido a esto lo que deseas lograr es imposible. Tus opciones son 1) Crear tu proprio programa de reproducción de videos que se cierre al apretar `ESC`. 2) Olvidarte de la tecla `ESC` y cerrar el programa de reproducción de video con el comando TASKKILL especificando dentro del script el tiempo de duración del video para que no se cierre durante la reproducción del video.

Comment: Por lo que respecta a tu preocupación de que el script se cierre tras haber cerrado el reproductor de video. Que esto no te quite el sueño, mientras haya una tarea por realizar el script no se cerrará (a menos que ocurra un error) y siempre puedes impedir su cierre aun cuando no quedan más las tareas por ejecutar utilizando el comando PAUSE el cual detiene el script esperando que se presione una tecla para continuar.

Comment: Buen día Ariel, agradezco tu ayuda, tu apoyo, tu interés y tu tiempo, muchas gracias, seguiré insistiendo en buscar una manera fácil , ya que no soy experto en programación, pero se que en esta área, todo es posible, por lo pronto, he logrado que vlc abra en pantalla completa, que no ponga el nombre del video al pie de la pantalla y colocando intro.exe, al inicio del cmd , al finalizar el video y cerrarse ya este intro.exe esperando el clíck de inicio. Nuevamente muchísimas Gracias, un abrazo virtual para ti.

Comment: Bueno amigo, desgraciadamente también la programación tiene sus limitaciones. Están los derechos de copyright que a veces impiden aportar modificas a los programas aunque sean open source como VLC.
Espero que puedas lograr lo que te propones, un saludo.

Comment: Mi buen amigo lo logre, lo que hice fue convertir el Videointro.mp4 a VideoIntro.exe (no indico su nombre, porque no se si es permitido), aquí esta configurado para que se ejecute en fullscreen, entonces primero se carga el programa intro.exe, de tal manera que si finaliza el video o se presiona ESC, queda en pantalla intro.exe esperando el click el click de inicio.  Lo probe como 20 veces y siempre funciono, el cmd quedo de la siguiente forma:  @echo off
start C:\Intro\intro.exe
start  C:\Users\VideoIntro.exe
exit

Answer (score 1):

Se convierte video.mp4 a video.exe, con la configuración deseada (ej: pantalla completa), el cmd queda así:

```
@echo off
start C:\Intro\intro.exe
start  C:\Users\VideoIntro.exe
exit
```

Lo que hace es:

- Ejecutar intro.exe
- Ejecutar videointro.exe sobre intro.exe
- Cerrar la ventana de cmd

Entonces si se presiona ESC, se cierra el videointro.exe, mas no intro.exe, ya que este último necesita una confirmación para cerrarse.

Cabe destacar que se debe utilizar un programa para convertir el video a .exe para que se agreguen durante la conversión los códecs necesarios a la ejecución del video, es decir, no se trata de renombrar la extensión de mp4 a exe. Es una conversión completa del archivo, los programas que probé hasta obtener el video como me interesaba son:

- AudioVideo To Exe v2.1
- DrmSoft Video to EXE Encryptor v10.4
- GreenForce v1.20
- MakeInstantPlayer v1.60

Comment: Cada vez entiendo menos lo que quieres hacer. Si das una extensión `.exe` a un video y te limitas a hacer `start video.exe` sin especificar el programa con el cual ejecutar el video (ej: `start vlc.exe p.exe`), entonces dará error. Intenté hacer lo que dices y no funciona. Debes argumentar más tu respuesta.

Comment: Por ejemplo, es imperativo que respondas en tu respuesta a esto: ¿Cómo convertiste el video de `mp4` a `exe` y cómo configuraste el video en pantalla completa?

Comment: Buen día Ariel, daré respuesta, por el respeto y dedicación a mi pregunta, lo cual para mi es encomiable, tomando en cuenta de que en esta comunidad, hay una gran, gran cantidad de personas que poseen mucho mas conocimiento que yo, mas no porque tu lo ordenas (es imperativo que respondas), lamentablemente tienes razón, debo argumentar más.